# 24lc256 EEPROM page writing problem

Tags: arduino, i2c, wire, eeprom, sparkfun

I have a question about my EEPROM Project recently started. why there is a maximum of 16-byte is Writing into EEPROM in below code. when we able to writing 64byte into the single page using page write according to the datasheet.  **there is any limitation of i2c buffer or page buffer**
. For example, the comment said /*Theoretically, the 24LC256 has a 64-byte page write buffer but
we'll write 16 at a time to be safe*/

what is mean by theoretically? is mean that we can not write the 64 bytes of data at once.

I share code with you. which I take reference from Sparkfun Reading and Writing guide
https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/reading-and-writing-serial-eeproms/all

EEPROM IC -  24lc256
Microcontroller ic - Atmega 32u4 ic
Library - Wire library

```
//Include the Wire I2C Library
#include <Wire.h>

/*This address is determined by the way your address pins are wired.
In the diagram from earlier, we connected A0 and A1 to Ground and 
A2 to 5V. To get the address, we start with the control code from 
the datasheet (1010) and add the logic state for each address pin
in the order A2, A1, A0 (100) which gives us 0b1010100, or in 
Hexadecimal, 0x54*/

#define EEPROM_ADR 0x50

/*Theoretically, the 24LC256 has a 64-byte page write buffer but 
we'll write 16 at a time to be safe*/ 

#define MAX_I2C_WRITE 16 

byte tempStore[MAX_I2C_WRITE];

void setup()
{

//Start the I2C Library
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.setClock(400000);

//Start the serial port
  Serial.begin(19200);

//Here is where we'll keep track of where in the memory we're writing
  long currentSpot = 0;
  long timerReset = 0;
  byte counter = 0;

  //Here we listen for bytes on the serial port and increment
  //the counter as we store them in our tempStore variable
  while (1)
  {
    while (Serial.available())
    {
      tempStore[counter++] = Serial.read(); //Read this byte into the array

      if (counter == MAX_I2C_WRITE)
      {
      //Once we've collected a page worth, go ahead and do 
      //a page write operation
        writeEEPROMPage(currentSpot);
        counter = 0; //Reset
        currentSpot += MAX_I2C_WRITE;
      }

      timerReset = millis();
    }

    if (millis() - timerReset > 2000)
    {
      Serial.println(currentSpot);
      timerReset = millis();
    }
  }

}

void loop()
{
    // Don't do anything here
}

/* This is the 3 step memory writing procedure that
we talked about. First, we send the MSB of the address. 
Then we send the LSB of the address. Then we send the data that we want to store. */

void writeEEPROMPage(long eeAddress)
{

  Wire.beginTransmission(EEPROM_ADR);

  Wire.write((int)(eeAddress >> 8)); // MSB
  Wire.write((int)(eeAddress & 0xFF)); // LSB

  //Write bytes to EEPROM
  for (byte x = 0 ; x < MAX_I2C_WRITE ; x++)
    Wire.write(tempStore[x]); //Write the data

  Wire.endTransmission(); //Send stop condition
}
```

Comment: What is the problem or question?

Comment: I'd guess that at some point before writing the library the author had some trouble getting a full 64-byte page write to work (possibly didn't understand the page address wrap-around or something like that, since I don't see any mention of it in that code). So instead of figuring it out he just limits himself to shorter writes and calls it done. There is no good reason for *you* to not use the device's full 64-byte page buffer, as long as you take the time to read and understand the relevant section of the datasheet.

Comment: You should ask the author of the tutorial this question.

Comment: @Justme is question